# Addding hooks to bootstrap menu

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Hi I am trying to amend my bootstrap menu to use Hooks (react) thus being able to toggle the menu when the screen is mobile size.

I have the following but I am stuck :-(

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link, NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

const NavigationBar = () => {
  const [isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = useState(false);

  return (
    <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top always-solid">
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <Link className="navbar-brand" to="/">
          GRT
        </Link>
        <button
          className="navbar-toggler"
          type="button"
          aria-controls="navbarNav"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation"
          onClick={() => setIsExpanded(!isExpanded)}
        >
          <span className="custom-toggler-icon">
            <i className="fa fa-bars"></i>
          </span>
        </button>
        <div
          className="collapse navbar-collapse"
          isExpanded={isExpanded}
          id="navbarNav"
        >
          <ul className="navbar-nav mx-auto">
            <li className="nav-item active">
              <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/">
                Home<span className="sr-only">(current)</span>
              </NavLink>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <NavLink
                className="nav-link"
                to="/stories"
                onClick={() => setIsExpanded(!isExpanded)}
              >
                Stories
              </NavLink>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <NavLink
                className="nav-link"
                to="/about"
                onClick={() => setIsExpanded(!isExpanded)}
              >
                About Us
              </NavLink>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <NavLink
                className="nav-link"
                to="/contact"
                onClick={() => setIsExpanded(!isExpanded)}
              >
                Contact Us
              </NavLink>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default NavigationBar;
```

I am expecting the menu to behave if it was using jQuery as per normal.

I get the I will need to move to useEffect to manage any clicking outside of the menu to close the Menu later but I am struggling to implement this at this time.

I have tried a numbe rof other solutions but they fail at this time and hooks seems the most slick and will I am hoping provide a better coding experience

Comment: What do you think setting an isExpanded property on a div is supposed to do? I think you need to set a [class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/#how-it-works)

Comment: Can't you do it using CSS hover? Do you really need to use state?

Comment: I suggest you take a look into `styled-components`. It makes it so much easier to achieve what you're looking for. https://www.styled-components.com/

Comment: thanks for looking I moved to React-Bootstrap this has now fixed my issue :-)